# Can I programmatically open a turbo_frame?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbo-frames

I have a list of documents(`index.html.erb`) where I can click a document to load details (`show.html.erb`) in a turbo_frame modal. This works well. There is a preview button that goes to a non turbo view for previewing an attachment. From here I want to click a back button to go back to the `index.html.erb` page but I'd also like to trigger the `show.html.erb` modal so they are technically back where they started. I was attempting to just force a redirect in the controller to the documents#show but this changes the route to /show and closing the modal gives you a blank page. Is it possible to open a turbo_frame without a click?

Comment: You are mixing Single page App concepts to classic navigation. When you click on the preview, if it is in a Turbo frame, then basically you don't change page. A good solution would to load your attachment view in a Turbo frame, with a higher Z-index so that it overrides your preview. Otherwise if you want to keep your attachment a different URL, then make your back button hit the index route with method `:post`, then you can add a turbo stream to populate the preview frame. It makes index to both accept `:get` and `:post` though .. Not too sure if right actually..

Comment: Also I have read that using `data-method` with :get it was possible to trigger turbo stream format in the background. Not done this myself though. You may have to try a few things and lurk Hotwired forum.

Comment: @Maxence Unfortunately I have to be on a new page for the preview (third-party issue) I've not dealt with streams yet so I'll dig in to that. I've contacted a turbo-rails contributor and he suggested there isn't a clean solution. I've implemented his suggestion of query params. So in my case I'm looking for a DOM element and then calling `.click()` to force the turbo frame action. It works decently. I just wish I could `redirect_to index_path(turbo_frame: modal (@document)) ` but oh well